# Inno Setup password verification via HTTP Post

Tags: php, inno-setup, pascalscript

Can someone help with password verification in Inno Setup, I currently have the below Inno Setup code (found on this site), what I would like to do is check the password against a password held on the server.

I have a PHP page containing MySQL code to check the database and if the Password is found it will send a response of  ‘Correct’
If the Password is not found it returns ‘Password Denied.

I think the issue is the setup is not sending the password in the `WinHttpReq.Send` (password) section.

I have included the Inno Setup code and the PHP code below.

If I put a genuine password in the code
`WHERE password='genuine licence'` I get the correct response and the install continues.

```
function CheckPassword(Password: String): Boolean;
var
  returnvalue: boolean;
  WinHttpReq: Variant;
begin
  result := false;
  MsgBox (password, mbInformation, MB_OK);  //show entered password before send
  WinHttpReq := CreateOleObject('WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1');
  WinHttpReq.Open('POST', 'website.php', false);
  WinHttpReq.SetRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  WinHttpReq.Send (Password);

  if WinHttpReq.ResponseText = 'Correct !' then
    result := true;

  if WinHttpReq.ResponseText = 'Access Denied !' then
    result := false;
end;
```

And the PHP code

```
$password = $_POST["password"];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM clients WHERE password='$password'";
if ($result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql))
{
    $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if($rowcount ==0)
    {
        die("Password Denied !");
    }
    if($rowcount==1)
    {
        die("Correct !");
    }
```

I would eventually like to send two bits of information for verification but I would like to get the above working first.

Will be very grateful for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Where's the server host name? How could this possibly work, if you do not specify, where the password should be sent to?

   ```pascal
   WinHttpReq.Open('POST', 'https://www.example.com/website.php', false);
   ```
2. You send the password as is. While you specify the `Content-Type` to be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. This content type has a specific format, that must include an argument name at least. How else would PHP know that the field is named `password`?

   ```pascal
   WinHttpReq.Send('password=' + Password);
   ```

   But to make this work correctly, you also have to URL-encode the password.

   Easier might be to write the password as is (as you are doing already) and read a raw request data on the server side:

   ```php
   $password = file_get_contents("php://input");
   ```
3. You really need to protect your server-side code against an [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).
4. You should be sending a checksum of the password only for security. E.g. using the [`GetSHA1OfString`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_getsha1ofstring).

   Side effect is that with the checksum, you do not have to care for URL encoding, as the checksum won't contain any special characters.